# How can I get notified about the publishing of ransomware decryption keys

Tags: cryptography, malware, decryption, ransomware

My computer had been hijacked by "Cryptolocker" a ransomware you might be well aware of. The nasty ransomware has encrypted most of my documents and video files. I used an anti-malware and removed the ransomware from my PC. But my files are left encrypted. I tried to search for a decryption tool on the net and I found decryption tools for files locked by teslacrypt, criptoXXX etc but not for files locked by cryptolocker. I used those tools and they are not working for me. I wont be paying any ransom to those hackers. Now I guess the only option is to wait until the hackers get caught and the decryption keys get uncovered and published. Now my question is how do I get notified if the decryption keys are uncovered and published. What websites do I need to constantly visit to get notified? By the way do you know any ways to decrypt    files locked by cryptolocker?

Comment: Check out https://www.nomoreransom.org/ where several security companies try to work together in offering a single place for the information you need. And you can probably forget that the hackers get caught, but it might be that they made mistakes when encrypting the data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , please make an answer of this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow discussions at bleeping computer forum dedicated to ransomware, several computer experts post there info on successful ransomware decrypting cases - http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/f/239/ransomware-help-tech-support/

Answer (score 3):

Several security companies and also Europol and other policy agencies maintain together the site [nomoreransom.org](https://www.nomoreransom.org). This site tries to offer a single place for information about current ransomware and also for the current tools which are available to decrypt the data.