# How can I decrypt a ransomware encrypted imme files

Tags: encryption, ransomware

I have tried multiple online available ransom decryption but they don't seem to be working, can you please guide which tool can assist me?

I have attached the encrypted files snapshot with this post.

These are database files and only these are encrypted, rest of the application is working fine.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139879/how-can-i-get-notified-about-the-publishing-of-ransomware-decryption-keys).

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal forum. I see you have posted this problem elsewhere but have not carried the same details here. You have been told which decryptor to use.